# On the strange label location using node, anchor and resistor

Tags: labels, tikz-node, tikz-circuit-lib, anchor

Let us assume that we have 2 resistors one on the positive x axis and the one on the negative x-axis, shown below:

[image]

I want to label them by `R`using a node whose south anchor located at the north anchor of the resistor. I am not interested way other ways of labeling. The strange fact is when we use the just mentioned above anchoring the results of labeling wont be symmetric. One right label will be higher than the left lable in y-direction. Do you know why? And how to fix it?
Below is my code:

```
\documentclass[border=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {circuits.ee.IEC}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC,set resistor graphic=var resistor IEC graphic]
\draw [ help lines,xstep=.5cm,ystep=.5cm] (-2cm,-0.5cm) grid (2cm,0.5cm);
%drawing the positive x-axis resistor
\draw (0,0cm) to [resistor={name=roxp,pos=0.5  } ]  (2cm,0);
\node [anchor=south]at (roxp.north){$R$};
%drawing the negative x-axis resistor
\draw (0,0cm) to [resistor={name=roxn,pos=0.5  } ]  (-2cm,0);
\node [anchor=south]at (roxn.north){$R$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The anchors are rotated along with the resistor, so north for one is south for the other.

Comment: @JohnKormylo nailed it. In `circuitikz` (and probably in most Ti*k*Z libraries) it would be the same, anchors rotate rigidly with nodes.

Comment: John Kormylo you answered my question correctly would you please put your answer down and I accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment on the anchors of rotated components (although I prefer using `[l=$R$]` for simplicity).

```
\documentclass[border=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {circuits.ee.IEC}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC,set resistor graphic=var resistor IEC graphic]
\draw [ help lines,xstep=.5cm,ystep=.5cm] (-2cm,-0.5cm) grid (2cm,0.5cm);
%drawing the positive x-axis resistor
\draw (0,0cm) to [resistor={name=roxp,pos=0.5  } ]  (2cm,0);
\node [anchor=south]at (roxp.north){$R$};
%drawing the negative x-axis resistor
\draw (0,0cm) to [resistor={name=roxn,pos=0.5  } ]  (-2cm,0);
\node [anchor=south]at (roxn.south){$R$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you have some special reason that you not use option `info` or `info'`? Using it, showed diagram can be drawn (without bother with resistors anchors) as:

```
\documentclass[border=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {circuits.ee.IEC}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC,
                    set resistor graphic=var resistor IEC graphic]
\draw [help lines,xstep=.5cm,ystep=.5cm] (-2cm,-0.5cm) grid (2cm,0.5cm);
%drawing the positive x-axis resistor
\draw (0,0) to [resistor={info=$R$} ]  (2,0);
%drawing the negative x-axis resistor
\draw (0,0) to [resistor={info'=$R$} ]  (-2,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
Apparently OP is convinced that (s)he can manually better tweak label position as this is done by deliberately defined automatic positioning obtained by use of `info` option.

Anyway, for one resistor this can be done on the following way:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=rect]
\node[name=s,shape=var resistor IEC, draw, 
      minimum width=2cm,minimum height=0.4cm] {} (2,0);
\node[above=3mm] at (s.north) {$R$};
\draw (s.west) -- ++ (-0.5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

For other possibilities see sketch for resistors anchor positions as I mentioned in my comment below.

Comment: Zarko: the reason I prefer anchor is to get better control on the label location.

Comment: @Aria, and what is wrong with position of the showed labels? Some control over label position you can get if you for resistor use a node, but code is quite complex. See example on page 635, Ti*k*Z & PGF manual. Anyway, simpler code for drawing offer `circuitikz` package ...

Comment: Zarko I understand info or circuitikz work. But I liked to use anchor to control the distance between label and resistor.